# Porous petri dish

Tags: equipment

I was wondering if there is a type of glass dish with small holes in it to use as a filter.  I've found a few but they are either fritted glass disks or a type of funnel.

I was looking for something similar to just a petri dish with no stems or inserts.

Comment: What scale of filtration are you talking about?  Do you want to filter tiny crystals of a precipitate from its parent solution, or is this for coarser purposes (like a tea  strainer, but glass and flat)?

Comment: I was looking for coarser purposes.  I have found some vented petri dishes but those seem to only be slits on the side.  I was looking for something more like a cocktail strainer where the openings are pin holes and covering the bottom.

Comment: Very large (i mean, ~ 0.5-1 l) filtering funnerls with glass filter do exist. Also, see this http://www.amazon.com/Kimax-Glass-Crucible-Kimflow-Fritted/dp/B004PLMF7G . There are some types of glassware, using fritted glass disk, but said glassware usually is used for some very specific task.

Answer (score 1):

The closest I could think of are nozzle cover lids. Wouldn't such tool be ineffective at 'filter'-ing substances nonetheless?

Comment: what kind of nozzle cover lid?
Is it glass?

Comment: Most nozzle lids would be plastics or metal as glass would not be useful. However, I'm not sure whether a plastic lid could be transparent.

Comment: The glass part is more important, not the opacity.
I've seen borosilicate crucibles with the fritted glass insert but I was looking for something that I wouldn't have to change the strainer in the bottom.
Does something like that really not exist?